# javascript / jQuery : get selected text's container

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get the id of the container (say, id of the p or div) of a user selected text?

I want to make list of selected texts, user selects a text then clicks on a button to add to the list.
And when user clicks the text from the list i want to highlight the place where original selection was made. 
I need the id of the container because the selected text may not be unique and appear multiple times in the document.

i get the selected text like this [Return HTML from a user-selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652734/return-html-from-a-user-selection/4652824#4652824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way it can be achieved cross browser (untested)

```
var getSelectionContainer = function() { 

    if (document.selection){  // IE
        return document.selection.createRange().parentElement();
    }

    var select = window.getSelection();
    if (select.rangeCount > 0) {
       return select.getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode;
    }
};
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ameqH/)

**(Select some text before 5 Seconds then look in the console)**

## Links

> [MDN window.getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection)
>
> [MDN selection.getRangeAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/getRangeAt)
>
> [MDN range.startContainer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range.startContainer)
>
> [MDN selection.rangeCount](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/rangeCount)

Answer (score 2):

`window.getSelection().anchorNode` - Gives you the DOM element where the selection started
`window.getSelection().focusNode` - Gives you the DOM element where the selection ended

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FSelection

Comment: in Chrome(i assume all WebKit based browsers too):
anchorNode gives all of the text in the container where the selection is started.
focusNode gives all of the text in the container where the selection is ended.

Comment: And how can I get the array of the dom elements which the text was selected? anchorNode and focusNode  just returns the first and the last one. What about the middle ones?